# bootstrap datetime picker with 12 hour clock not displaying the meridian(am or pm) in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetime-format

i want to display the date_time format in this way `11/01/2013 12:00 AM` but currently it is displaying `11/01/2013 12:00 P` like this. the meridian indicator "P" always showing "P" instead of showing am or pm.

i am following this link [bootstrap date time picker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) for my rails app.

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
             format : 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm P'   
        });
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
             format : 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm a'   
        });
```

gives `DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm am`

or

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
             format : 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A'   
        });
```

gives `DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm AM`

Comment: I spent huge amount of time to check on net , but you solution worked. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I can´t test it at the moment. But id should be

```
format : 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A'
```

or

```
format : 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm a'
```

for big or small pm.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
format: 'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm A'
```

or

```
format: 'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss A'
```

or

```
format: 'DD-MM-YYYY - hh:mm:ss A'
```

or

```
format: 'DD-MM-YYYY :: hh:mm:ss A'
```

or

any other such possible combination. **Here the A in the end of format is responsible for showing AM or PM**

Answer (score 2):

any of the above solution is not worked for me
I have tried this, hope this help anyone

```
 format: 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii p'
```

where

- dd - Date
- mm - month
- yyyy - year
- hh - hour
- ii - minute
- p - show am/pm

This link is [very](https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) useful