# Change datetime format in jQuery

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I have using following jquery code snippet in an input field to pick date and time in my page

```
$('.timePicker').datetimepicker({
    format:'yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss',
    minDate: getFormattedDate(new Date())
});
```

**Current output is** : 2017/07/05 06:07:04

While in need the date and time format in following format

**Expected output** : 07/05/2017 06:07AM

Ho can i change this code for this purpose ?

Comment: You go read the documentation of the plugin regarding the `format` parameter ...

Answer (score 1):

```
   $('.timePicker').datetimepicker({
        ampm: true, // FOR AM/PM FORMAT
        format : 'g:i A'
    });
```

or

```
$('.timePicker').datetimepicker(
                {
                    format: 'DD MMM YYYY hh:mm A'

                });
```

this should do it

Answer (score 0):

Already there are similar questions available. Please refer the following links to find them. They will solve your problem.

[DateTimePicker AM/PM 01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270293/bootstrap-datetime-picker-with-12-hour-clock-not-displaying-the-meridianam-or-p)

[DateTimePicker AM/PM 02](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22848383/how-to-set-am-pm-format-in-jquery-using-datetimepicker)

Comment: If you believe this question has a duplicate please vote to close it as such.