# Formatting Bootstrap 3 Datepicker for MySQL

Tags: php, datepicker

I'm using https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ and there's a bit of a formatting issue.

When the format is set like this `format: 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm'`, it looks nice for the user, as most people don't think in military time and understand AM/PM better.  If 7:45AM (for example) is selected, `$('#datepicker-data').val();` will return `07:45`, but if 7:45PM is selected `$('#datepicker-data').val();` will **also** return `07:45`.

I'll be needing to insert the selected date and time into a MySQL database.  Is there a way to get the user friendly input AND the MySQL friendly formatting for DB insert?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270293/bootstrap-datetime-picker-with-12-hour-clock-not-displaying-the-meridianam-or-p

Comment: @DeadManAlive: That's helpful.  Thanks.  I could do some PHP to see if it was AM or PM and then convert to the standard DATETIME MySQL format, but it would be nice if there was a way to get it as military time for a straight DB insert.  Do you know if that sort of option exists?